# In fabric deployment, what's advantage of domain address than ip address in peer setting

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

In fabric deploy environment, what's the priority or advantage of setting the peer address with domain address than ip address?
Would it be helpful to the migration of fabric data to a new environment?
If peers in different computers,should the dns delay be in consideration?
Does ledger file contains the ip info of the peer & the order, or just the name label of peer & order? I wonder if peer & order ip changed, the ledger data is suitable for the new ip environment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making migration easy is the advantage of using domain addresses. addresses are related to docker containers and used to send grpc requests. 
For running on different computers consider running a dns server and map ip's to domain names.
No ip related info is inside ledger, so you can easily migrate your data.